# PDO statement returns zero rows for date WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two files, one is page that shows the latest additions to my site, the other is a link to the first page.

problem: if i include a `like` keyword instead of `=` in the `sql`, the query works. however, when i use `=` (which is what i want), it returns zero rows.

code snippets:

### front-page.php

```
echo "On " . max($last_date) . ", we had <a href='/latest-txt.php?date=$md'>" . count($last_posts) . "</a> text posts!"
```

### latest-text.php

```
$query = $_GET[$md];

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE $db_tb_atr_name5 = ? ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 0, 15");

if($stmt->execute(array("%$query%"))){

echo "Search Results<ol>";

while($data_fetch = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<li>";

echo "<div class='tagtext'>AUTHOR: ";    
echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name2], 0,160)," "," ";
echo "TAG: ";
echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name3], 0,160)," ";
//echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name4], 0,160)," ";

echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='tagtext'>MESSAGE: ";
echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
echo "</div>";

//echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);

echo "</li><hr/>";

    }

}    

echo "</ol>";
```

can anybody help? thanks.

Comment: If you want to use wildcards, you will have to use `LIKE`.

Comment: Remove the two `%` signs when using the `=` sign

Comment: Of course, it's PDO to blame. Care to verify what's in the `$query` variable?

Comment: @adeoba What is the datatype of your `$db_tb_atr_name5` column? If it is `DATETIME` then using `=` will not work. `2013-06-15 14:00:00 ≠ 2013-06-15`.

Comment: @Spero datatype is DATE

Comment: @adeoba Have you looked at a `var_dump` of `$_GET` or `$query`?  Make sure there are no leading/trailing characters. If  you take the final output of the sql does it produce the expected results when run directly in MySQL?

Comment: the sql when run directly produces the right results. how do i take a var_dump ? thanks.

Comment: `var_dump();` If you don't have xdebug or something similar configured. wrap the var_dump in some `<pre>` - `echo '<pre>' . var_dump($_GET, $query) . '</pre>';`

Comment: var_dump : array(1) { ["date"]=> string(10) "2013-06-15" } NULL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38297/discussion-between-spero-shiropetto-and-adeoba)

Comment: @adeoba I take it that you left out the ending semi-colon in `front-page.php` - typo, right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, the `$md` variable was not being set (see `var_dump` in comments above), as well as the wildcard `%` being used with the equal operator.

Comment: @Fred-ii: yes! sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. replace `$query=$_GET[$md]` with `$query=$_GET['date']`
2. replace `"%$query%"` with `$query`

(both as suggested by some of you :) )

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying use `%` as wilcard in your search criteria without `LIKE` which means concatenating `%` character to `$query` value.

You are querying

```
SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE $db_tb_atr_name5 = '%2013-09-30%' ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 0, 15
```

because of there is no row which has a value `'%2013-09-30%'` in your table the query returns zero rows.

You should change `$stmt->execute(array("%$query%"))` to `$stmt->execute(array($query))` before removing `like`.

I suggest you to change your way binding parameter.

write

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

before executing and execute

```
if($stmt->execute())
{
  ...
}
```

In addition to this we have to know what value `$query` and `$md` have.

So take a try with `$_GET['date']`.

Another approach is to understand what is wrong:
1. If you get 0 rows with no error message, your query works fine.
2. If you get 0 rows without knowing you have an exception let's make a little modification on your code:

```
try
{

    $query = $_GET[$md];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE $db_tb_atr_name5 = ? ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 0, 15");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    {
        echo "Search Results<ol>";

        while($data_fetch = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<div class='tagtext'>AUTHOR: ";    
            echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name2], 0,160)," "," ";
            echo "TAG: ";
            echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name3], 0,160)," ";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class='tagtext'>MESSAGE: ";
            echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</li><hr/>";
        }  
    }    

    echo "</ol>";

} 
catch (PDOException $pdoe) 
{
    throw $pdoe;
}
```

Comment: removing the wildcards has not worked i'm afraid. $query = 2013-06-15

Comment: $md = max($last_date). using bindValue still gives zero rows.

Comment: i don't want to use ['date'] because i want the latest date.

Comment: @adeoba $_GET[$md] is equal to $_GET['date'], isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

It is due to the `%` wildcard within your execute array, the [Equal Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) `=` is a comparison operator and takes `%` as a literal character.

`LIKE` is pattern matching that can use wildcards. [MySQL 5.7: String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
%   Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
_   Matches exactly one character
```

Comment: Please leave a comment/recommendation of change if you're going to downvote.